# How to make TreeView send CDDS_*ERASE events?

Tags: winapi, treeview, custom-draw

I'm implementing a customized TreeView with win32. Have the following custom draw code:

```
void treeCustomDraw(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    NMCUSTOMDRAW* pNMCustomDraw = (NMCUSTOMDRAW*)pNMHDR;
    NMTVCUSTOMDRAW* pNMTVCustomDraw = (NMTVCUSTOMDRAW*)pNMHDR;
 
    switch (pNMCustomDraw->dwDrawStage)
    {
    case CDDS_PREPAINT:
        *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW | CDRF_NOTIFYITEMERASE | CDRF_NOTIFYPOSTERASE;
        break;     
    case CDDS_POSTERASE:
    case CDDS_ITEMPOSTERASE:
        // never happens
        *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;
        break;     
    case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
        *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;
        break;     
    case CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT:
        // some working code
}
```

With all the documented ways I tried to make the view sending any of the `CDDS_*ERASE` message, with no luck at all, [despite the docu saying the corresponding CDRF has to be returned from CDDS_PREPAINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-customdraw). Am I doing/wanting something utterly impossible?

UPD: The custom draw is done in the window procedure. The `pResult` is correctly returned, as `CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT` is caught and correctly processed. Just the `CDDS_*ERASE` remain untriggered.

Usecase: I need to catch the moment of TreeView item being erased off its previous coordinates, so being able to run some custom cleanup code. The `CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT` goes just well with custom drawing, but the drawing is duplicated during the scrolling and navigation, because of no way to erase the old custom stuff.

Comment: I do this indeed. CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT is correctly messaged and caught..

Comment: It looks like the tree doesn't send the erase messages. CDDS_PREPAINT, CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT, CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT and CDDS_POSTPAINT are all it sends.

Comment: [Is this message handled in a dialog procedure or window procedure?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-customdraw#remarks)

Comment: The window procedure.

Comment: @JonathanPotter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-customdraw-tree-view does imply that item POSTERASE is a thing for TreeView (not that one should trust MSDN).

Comment: @Anders Knowing the quality of their documentation I would put money on that just being a copy-and-paste job and not at all related to the behaviour of the actual control.